# Included part of a phtml file in CMS page

Tags: template, phtml

I can include a phtml file with the following

```
{{block type="core/template" template="page/page.phtml"}}
```

But is there anyway I can include only part of its content that is needed and use another part of it somewhere else?

example:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(51);

echo '<p>The price for product 51 is £' . $_product->getFinalPrice() . '</p>';

$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(52);

echo '<p>The price for product 52 is £' . $_product->getFinalPrice() . '</p>';
```

Then on a banner for product 51 it would show the correct price.

I would also need it to work for configurable products that works in the same way but shows the lowest priced simple product only as follows:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(80);
if($_product->isconfigurable()) {
$conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($_product); 
$simple_collection = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->addFilterByRequiredOptions()
                    ->addAttributeToSort('Price', 'asc'); 

foreach($simple_collection as $simple_product){ 
echo '<p>Order yours now for only ' . Mage::helper('core')->currency($simple_product->getPrice()) . '</p>';
break;
}   
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example? I don't really understand what you mean

Comment: Added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then your template can look like this

```
<?php 
if ($this->getData('product_id')) :
    $productId = $this->getData('product_id');
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
?>
<p>The price for product 51 is £<?php echo $_product->getFinalPrice()?></p>
<?php endif;?>
```

Then you can use it like this:

You can do it like this in one place:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="page/page.phtml" product_id="51"}}
```

and like this in an other place

You can do it like this:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="page/page.phtml" product_id="52"}}
```

To summarize...you can pass parameters to templates and blocks that use `{{block}}` directive and later use those values as you need.

Comment: You are the man. thank you. please would you help me with the configurable one aswell. I have updated my question. again thanks :)

Comment: Sorted it. Just added the variable and it worked. I missed a quote in the cms page thats why it didnt work initially. thanks for your help :)